# Casting void* in constructor and accessing value

Tags: c++

The following code does not compile as it can not see a way to deference a void pointer despite the fact a cast is taking place in the constructor. Is there anyway to get this code to compile or turn off the type safety?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

IntWrapper(int _value) : value{ nullptr }
{
    value = new int(_value);
    value = static_cast<int*>(value);
}

int main()
{
    IntWrapper* foo = new IntWrapper(10);
    cout << *foo->value;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I should note that whilst this code is a console application it is intended as a test for code that is being written in Unreal Engine. It is for this reason that I cannot use class templates to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: Why are you using void pointers

Comment: I need a class that can be a fixed number of types only(int,float,double,etc) and cannot use a template. This is a simplified version of the class as it is a pain to test this in Unreal. It is also a thought exercise I suppose as I realise I could achieve this by defining multiple types inside the wrapper.

Comment: I forgot about union, that will probably work. I'll look at that now. Thanks!

Comment: Also std::any - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: You made the mistake of believing that the compiler knows what's behind a void pointer.  It doesn't.  You have to tell the compiler what the void pointer is pointing to by casting it to the appropriate type, which you failed to do in the `cout`.

Comment: I'm aware of why it won't compile but want to know if i can bypass the safety and force it to compile as after the cast the type is in fact correct. A union works as an alternative but isn't quite what I want. I want the functionality to be entirely inside the struct.

Comment: You are storing a `void*`. It doesn't matter how many times you cast that value to `int*` in other places, if you don't do it at the place you want to dereference it, the compiler has no way of knowing what you want it to do. That you cannot dereference a `void*` has nothing to do with "type safety" — it is simply a meaningless operation. There is no such thing as a "void".

Comment: Put `IntWrapper`'s definition in the question please. Read about how to present a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

`new int` returns a an `int*`. Casting an `int*` to `int*` is a no-op and accomplishes nothing. After you cast the result of `new` to itself, you store it in a `void*` variable, which implicitly casts it to `void*`.

When you access `foo->value`, the type is `void*` because that's the type you defined for `value`. Whatever you do in the constructor won't change that. If you want to cast the void pointer, here's where you do it. That is you can cast the  `foo->value` to `int*` and then dereference that.

Of course it would be much easier to just have `value` be an `int*` in the first place.

Comment: Or not use `void*` in the first place :)

Comment: You will have to make some leaps of faith in terms of accepting this is the implementation that works for the situation. Hypothetically would there be any way to disable the type checking and force the compiler to proceed? I can of course implement the functionality differently so there is no void* but would liek to know if this is possible under any imposed circumstances.

Comment: @InvertedIdeals Proceed with what? Proceed in calling the int overload for operator<<? That's impossible without you telling the compiler that ` foo->value` points to an `int`. There's no way for the compiler to figure that out itself when `foo->value` is declared as `void*`.

Comment: @InvertedIdeals To elaborate a bit: You seem to think that the code only fails because the compiler has safety concerns, but that's not the case. The compiler *needs* to know the type of the operand in order to execute the right overload. That is `cout << aFloat` executes different code `cout << anInt`. So if the compiler doesn't know the type, it doesn't know which code to execute. So you'll need to tell it the type - there's no way around that. (Plus the compiler won't even know how many bytes to read without knowing the type)

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you use "->" you are dereferencing the term on the left of it.

In your case *foo , but since foo is an IntWrapper * , then *foo is an IntWrapper.

So the syntax is foo->value or (*foo).value.

Also everything that has been said in the other answer is true , this static cast does absolutely nothing.

therefore the correct code would be more like this :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct IntWrapper
{
    IntWrapper(int _value) : value{ new int(_value) } {}
    void * value;
};

int main()
{
    IntWrapper * foo = new IntWrapper(10);
    cout << *((int *)(foo->value));
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Since you are making an int wrapper , the void * type inside the struct is not very helpfull. making it an int * would give you better error handling , and no need to cast foo->value to print it or access it as an int.

Comment: I probably obscured the actual question by calling it 'IntWrapper' . I can of course return the memory address by doing foo->value but I want to be able to do *foo->value and perform the cast inside of the wrapper struct. It is more of a curiosity rather than a necessity to have this implementation.

Comment: You cannot do that if your value is  a void * . It is an incomplete type and therefore  cannot be dereferenced. You MUST use a complete type to dereference it.